# How do I convert a part of a CS:GO demo file into a AVI video file? (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I want to be able to render/export the first round of one of my competitive matches into a video format, preferably a higher quality one like AVI. I have a slower system, so I want to be able to render it slowly with 1080p, and 60FPS. I'm running an up-to-date version of Ubuntu 16.04. Please keep in mind I have never done anything with demo files before, besides watch them on GOTV, so I'm clueless.

Comment: have you tried to just record the replay with OBS?

Comment: MY PC isn't powerful enough to use recording software.

Comment: Then you don't have a way. Some kind of Console command like in CS source dont exists

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually there is a way to directly record your demo files in avi.

Check out [this](http://www.ryadel.com/en/csgo-how-to-convert-csgo-demo-to-avi-files/) article.

In order to start recording from your demo you should use these commands:
`playdemo <demo_file_name>` starts the demo (the file should be in your `/csgo/` root folder)
`sv_cheats 1; host_framerate 60` sets the framerate to 60fps
`startmovie <demo_avi_name> avi` starts recording as AVI

Once you enter the `startmovie` command you will be prompted to choose a video codec. I used Lagarith lossless codec but most other codecs should work fine.

After I recorded the demo file with the command I converted it from avi to mp4 (3rd party program) but because the software I used to convert the file was a bit glitchy it didn't convert it correctly and the mp4 file was laggy. So just make sure you keep the avi file even after converting it to mp4, just in case.

FYI: A 60fps 1080p mp4 video can lag on some computers, so if it looks laggy make sure to go through a section of the mp4 video frame by frame to test if it really is 60fps.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way built into CS:GO

Try using recording software to directly capture the output from your graphics cards frame buffer.

FRAPS, for one, is very resource intensive. As you stated your system is not very capable hardware-wise, try the freeware "ScreenCap Free" or "Visusoft ScreenDir Gomen lite". They are both free to use and don't put a huge strain on your RAMs and DIMs.